# Creation of table in snowflake with current month & year like 202108

Tags: shell, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've to create a table in snowflake from snowsql with the current date like "test_202108" where 2021 is year & 08 is month.

I'm automating the process using shell script. Like creation of table, put & copy commands.

Can anyone please help me on that.

Thanks
Pavan Kumar

Comment: Are you looking to write a script that will be called from snowsql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the following :
Set a variable which is concatenation of year and month:

```
set value= (select 'table'||year(current_date()))||(select month(current_date()));
```

and with this use identifier keyword to reference the variable in the following :

```
CREATE table identifier($value) (col integer);
```